# How to break bigger chunk into smaller ones to fit into max chunk?

Tags: spray, chunked-encoding, transfer-encoding, http-chunked

My server is sending me chunked encoded data and I am able to get the chunked response in my client. The problem I am facing is that some chunks are too big, ca 10 MB. I am getting an exception as I have set max chunk size to 2M.

Is there any way to break this bigger chunk into smaller ones?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Not sure what version of Spray you're using but starting from version 1.1 there is `incoming-auto-chunking-threshold-size` setting ([details here](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-can/configuration/)). [Here is](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/examples/spray-can/simple-http-server/src/main/scala/spray/examples/DemoService.scala) example of service that supports chunked upload.

There are still number of limitations at the moment. You could read relevant discussion in [open ticket](https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/281).

Answer (score 0):

you can devide big chunk in smaller chunks by using RandomAccessFile.
I had same problem. I resolved it using RandomAccessFile.

you can do it following way.

```html
byte[] bytes;
String filePath = "path";
RandomAccessFile file1 = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");

      file1.seek(0);
      bytes = new byte[(int)file1.length()/3];
      file1.read(bytes);
      file1.close();
      String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```